# Delete / Unset existing custom options on product

Tags: product, magento-1, custom-options

I have created an observer on catalog_product_save_before in order to add custom options to a product.

What i don't manage to achieve is clearing out existing custom options beforehand.

Here is my code:

```
       $product = $observer->getProduct();    

       $option1 = array (
            'is_delete' => 0,
            'title' => 'extra Option for that product',
            'type' => 'drop_down',
            'is_require' => 1,
            'sort_order' => 1,
            'values' => array (
                0 => array (
                    'value_id' => '3',
                    'title' => 'Yes',
                    'price' => 10.00,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => NULL,
                    'sort_order' => 1,
                ),
                1 => array (
                    'value_id' => 3,
                    'title' => 'No',
                    'price' => 0.00,
                    'price_type' => 'fixed',
                    'sku' => NULL,
                    'sort_order' => 2,
                ),
            ),
        );           


    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);    
    $product->getOptionInstance();
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option */
    $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
    $product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option1);         
    $product->setHasOptions(true);
```

this does not seem to have any effect:

```
     $product->getOptionInstance()->unsetOptions();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have ended up doing it like this :

```
         $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    
         $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write'); 
         $table = '`catalog_product_option` O JOIN `catalog_product_option_type_value` V on O.option_id=V.option_id';    
         $query = "DELETE O, V FROM {$table} WHERE `product_id`=".(int)$product->getId()."";     
         $writeConnection->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$product->getOptionInstance()->setOptions($option1);
```

This will reset the entire **$this->_options** array to the supplied array

```
/**
 * Set options for array
 *
 * @param array $options
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option
 */
public function setOptions($options)
{
    $this->_options = $options;
    return $this;
}
```

**Edit:** The above didn't seem to function as expected.

Why not try removing all the options before we make any changes?

```
$oldOptions = $product->getOptionInstance()->getOptions();
foreach ($oldOptions as $key => $option){
    $oldOptions[$key]['is_delete'] = 1;
}
// Set the old options back into the product options
$product->getOptionInstance()->setOptions($oldOptions);
// Save with the is_delete key
$product->getOptionInstance()->saveOptions();
```

Comment: no, this does not reset the entire options

Comment: @Matoeil I've updated my response with some more code, hopefully this will solve your issue.

Comment: this does not work coz $option is an array and not an object

Comment: @Matoeil Whoops! Sorry I'm reading the source and trying to interrupt stuff, I've updated it again to update the array. You may need to call the saveOptions function after.

Comment: Thanx for your help.do u know how to put the modified array back to the object then? could u provide a full working code?

Comment: @Matoeil From looking into the model you should be able to run **$product->getOptionInstance()->saveOptions();** which has code to check if the option has is_delete set to 1.

Comment: @Matoeil I've updated my response with some code which **should** work. It's not been tested.